# fix GUI after Disco Dingo upgrade

Tags: gnome, 19.04

After an upgrade of my system from 18.10 to 19.04, I find myself unable to use Ubuntu GUI anymore.

On boot, the login screen appear, but it's very unresponsive (like a slide show), and when I try to login, it invariably fails, and comes back to login screen.

Apart from that, the system seems to be working well. I can SSH into it, no problem. I can use a TUI, with Ctrl+Alt+F3 for example, and it works well too.

But that's obviously limitative. No GUI means no web, which obviously deprives of too many possibilities.

So I would like to fix that. I'm wondering what's the best course of action.

The best scenario would be to re-init something, or change a few parameters in gnome for example, reboot, and get the GUI finely working. It could be a graphic driver issue for example, though that doesn't tell me how to fix it.

Worse scenario would be to re-install the OS, with the slight hope that I could keep my user content (`/home` is in a different partition, specially for such purpose).

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem :
This was fixed by uninstalling and re-installing the graphics driver (nVidia).

Comment: How can we do that. I got the same issue. I have nvidia graphics

Comment: this didnt work for me nor did reinstalling DE

Answer (score 3):

One course of action would be to reinstall the desktop environment.  If you are using the default DE (GNOME3), then you can run these commands from a virtual terminal

`CTRL` + `ALT` + `F3` (as you've been doing)

then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
```

when that's finished

```
sudo reboot
```

If you have been using a different DE, substitute the corresponding package for `gnome-shell`

Comment: I would have loved for this suggestion to be correct. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. After reinstall and reboot, symptoms are still exactly the same.

Comment: Re-installing the graphics driver did the trick. The GUI now works correctly.