# Desktop unresponsive after Disco Dingo Upgrade

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 19.04, display-manager

I am experiencing some weird and very annoying UI issues after the Disco Dingo upgrade.

I have a NVIDIA Graphics Card.

My issues include no feedback from mouse clicks (however I can still see cursor movement) in the desktop environment and no feedback from keyboard events in the desktop environment. I have tried reinstalling the nvidia graphics drivers, changing the display manager, "disabling" wayland with gdm3, and reinstalling the gnome shell ([fix GUI after Disco Dingo upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142019/fix-gui-after-disco-dingo-upgrade)).

I dont know what else to try - PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Issue was a GNOME extension - not sure which yet